# Using NUnit with Installing Package or using DLL

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm using an application that uses Visual Studio and C# for it's built-in scripting. I want to use NUnit for testing but the environment doesn't understand nuget packages or add-on dll's so it discards anything that isn't source code each time it saves and reloads a project.

I was hoping that I might be able to get around this by including the full NUnit source code in a folder in the C# project and perhaps using something like the lite-runner to run the tests.

Any advise on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to test the C# source code using NUnit? And what do you mean with "the environment doesn't understand nuget packages"?

Comment: What is the environment?